# PHP Chat System MySQL Database Order by datesent sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php chat system that I am working on. I have an issue where the query statement to grab the message is selecting them, grouping them by the two users that it was sent to and from, and then outputs the html.

Right now it only is outputting from the beginning of the first chat id to the last id when a user goes to select a chat.

I would like to sort it by the most recent chat on top because as of the moment, it is going from top to bottom from the first user that has sent a message to the last user that has sent a message. For example, if "user 1" hasn't sent a message for a while, that user will always be the first one to be outputted by the query statement, even though "user 6" has sent 8 new chats, "user 6" will still be the last one on the list to select from, this should be the opposite and the newest chat group should appear on top. I just don't know how to do that with my SQL query.

My current query statement is:

```
$queryall = "SELECT DISTINCT mfrom FROM chat WHERE mto='user2'";
```

I know it's coded wrong for what I want, and i've tried a lot of different things, can't seem to get it to do what I want. I've tried order by datesent and grouping them, but couldn't get anything to work. I believe DISTINCT is not allowing me to do it based of syntax things I am not familiar with.

[mysql database row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKtiC.png)

[User2 chat view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQDr.png)

Comment: You've given almost nothing in terms of context here. Focus on the **code**, not images which convey presentation. Also [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/sql-server/sql-server-2016) is a Microsoft product and has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the tags. As for the code, it is not needed because the sql statement does all the work. The code you are looking for I assume is what outputs it in HTML and has nothing to do with grabbing the information from the sql database. The context is in the description. I need a fix my query statement so that it grabs the whole users chat based off the most recent one sent. If user one sent a chat a week ago and user 6 just sent a chat, user 6 should appear above user 1 in the output as explained above.

Comment: There's a lot of words in this question and not a lot of code, nor a problem as far as I can tell. Can you boil it down to something more minimal?

Comment: Sure, but I am confused on what you want to know. I need to grab chats between one user and another based of the last chat sent in the group with the query. A chat between user 1 and user 2 sent a week ago should not appear above in the list with a chat sent between user 6 and user 1 5 minutes ago. The query at the moment grabs the chats based on what user sent one first and then always puts that user in the first spot no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple `ORDER BY`:

```
$queryall = "SELECT DISTINCT mfrom FROM chat WHERE mto='user2' ORDER BY datesent DESC";
```

This orders your result set by column `datesent` in `DESC` (descending) order (newest to oldest when used on date/datetime column).

When your users have multiple messages, you may want to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`

```
$queryall = "SELECT mfrom FROM chat WHERE mto='user2' GROUP BY mfrom ORDER BY MAX(datesent) DESC";
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but phpmyadmin give me this. SQL query: Documentation


SELECT mfrom FROM chat WHERE mto='user2' ORDER BY datesent DESC GROUP BY mfrom LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY mfrom LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: My bad - GROUP BY goes before ORDER BY.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1055 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'chatdb.chat.datesent' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Try updated ORDER BY above

Comment: The version I am running is MySQL 5.7.15

Comment: See above using MAX() to get latest date value from the group